# Maximum recursion depth exceeded in python for calculates the exponential

Tags: python

I have tried this version is correct:

```
def recurPowerNew(base, exp):
    if exp == 0:
        return 1
    elif exp > 0 and exp % 2 == 1:
        return base * recurPowerNew(base, exp-1)
    elif exp > 0 and exp % 2 == 0:
        return recurPowerNew(base * base, exp / 2)
```

while this version appears error:

```
def recurPowerNew(base, exp):
    if exp == 0:
        return 1
    elif exp > 0 and exp % 2 == 1:
        return base * recurPowerNew(base, exp-1)
    elif exp > 0 and exp % 2 == 0:
        return recurPowerNew(recurPowerNew(base, 2), exp / 2)
```

The difference is the last `elif`.

Can anyone figure out why?

Comment: Returning a recursive function that in itself has a recursive function makes both need to be recursive. In the first example you'll be using O(n) for a recursive depth while in the second O(2^n)

Comment: Your last `elif` contains `recurPowerNew(base, 2)`.  Which ends up passing `elif exp > 0 and exp % 2 == 0` again on the next passthrough.  Which again calls `recurPowerNew(base, 2)` ...

Comment: Why are you repeating the `exp > 0` comparison? If `exp` is assumed non-negative you can simplify that conditions, and if this is not the case why aren't you handling the negative case?

Comment: In the second function, your base condition does not handle a exp of 2, so it will never resolve and infinitely recurse.

Answer (score 0):

On the last elif in the second version, you are calling your recursive function with itself as an argument.  This is leading to recursion within recursion, which will run so many times that it exceeds the maximum recursion depth.